# Como remover mascara no Delphi de um MaskEdit

Tags: delphi

Estou precisando remover o ponto e o traço de um MaskEdit no Delphi.
A mascara é ##.###-#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você estiver montando a máscara assim: ##.###-##;1;_ 

Quer dizer que ele está salvando os caracteres literalmente.

Para impedir isso, utilize o zero no lugar do 1, assim: ##.###-##;0;_

Dessa forma apenas os números serão considerados.